# Value classes, universal traits and the necessity of instantiation

Tags: scala, value-class, universal-trait

In the [specification of value classes](https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/core/value-classes.html), it says:

> A value class can only extend *universal traits* and cannot be extended itself. A *universal trait* is a trait that extends `Any`, only has `def`s as members, and does no initialization. Universal traits allow basic inheritance of methods for value classes, but they *incur the overhead of allocation*. For example

```
trait Printable extends Any {
  def print(): Unit = println(this)
}
class Wrapper(val underlying: Int) extends AnyVal with Printable

val w = new Wrapper(3)
w.print() // actually requires instantiating a Wrapper instance
```

## First Question

Now, I would take this to mean that the following (probably) **does not** require instantiation:

```
trait Marker extends Any
class Wrapper(val underlying: Int) extends AnyVal with Marker {
  def print(): Unit = println(this) //unrelated to Marker
}

val w = new Wrapper(3)
w.print() //probably no instantiation as print is unrelated to Marker
```

Am I correct?

## Second Question

And I would think there is an even chance as to whether this requires instantiation or not:

```
trait Printable extends Any {
  def print(): Unit //no implementation
}
class Wrapper(val underlying: Int) extends AnyVal with Printable {
  override def print() = println(this) //moved impl to value class
}

val w = new Wrapper(3)
w.print() // possibly requires instantiation
```

On the balance of probability, I would also think that no instantiation would be needed - am I correct?

### Edit

I'd not thought about the exact implementation of `print()` in the example:

```
def print(): Unit = println(this)
```

Let's say that I used the following instead:

```
def print(): Unit = println(underlying)
```

Would these cause instantiations?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Am I correct?

No, we can see it if we emit the final compilation output with `-Xprint:jvm`:

```
<synthetic> object F$Wrapper extends Object {
  final def print$extension($this: Int): Unit = 
    scala.Predef.println(new com.testing.F$Wrapper($this));
```

This is due to the fact `println` has a type signature requiring `Any`, so we're shooting ourselves in the foot here since we're effectively "treating the value class ttpe as another type".

Although the call is dispatched to the static method call:

```
val w: Int = 3;
F$Wrapper.print$extension(w)
```

We're still incurring the allocation inside `print$extension`.

---

If we stray away from using `Wrapper.this`, then your first assumption is indeed correct and we can see the compiler happily unwrap `Wrapper`:

```
<synthetic> object F$Wrapper extends Object {
  final def print$extension($this: Int): Unit = 
    scala.Predef.println(scala.Int.box($this));
```

And the call site now looks like this:

```
val w: Int = 3;
com.testing.F$Wrapper.print$extension(w)
```

This is valid for both of your examples now, as there is no need for any dynamic dispatch on the created interface.

Comment: Interesting. I'd actually not really meant to specifically consider the fact it was a call to `print(this)`. Presumably had I chosen `println(underlying)` no instantiation would have been necessary?

Comment: @oxbow_lakes I was wondering if you intentionally wanted `this` or not. I'll update the answer.

Comment: But it causes a call to `Int.box`? Pfft!

Comment: @oxbow_lakes `$this` now refers to the local value `$this: Int` in the method signature, not the `this` pointer. No allocations necessary now.

Comment: But your impl of `print$extension` is `scala.Predef.println(scala.Int.box($this));`

Comment: So the `Int` gets boxed into a `java.lang.Integer`

Comment: @oxbow_lakes `print$extension($this: Int)`. The only boxing is because we need an `Integer` instance for `println`, not an `Int`.

Comment: @oxbow_lakes Yes, it does, but no allocation of `Wrapper`. This is a limitation of `println`, again since it needs `Any`.

Comment: "As long as we reference this inside or outside the value class, we're trapped." I think this is wrong (or I don't understand what you mean). The problem is that here "a value class is treated as another type" (namely, a `Wrapper` as an `Any`); whether it's `this` or not, doesn't matter. And passing `this` to a method accepting a `Wrapper` is fine.

Comment: @Alexey Romanov `this` is problematic in the context of `println` because of `Any`, is what I meant. I'll clarify.

Comment: But why does `Int` need to be boxed to be considered an `Any`? `Int <: AnyVal <: Any`

Comment: I've asked this separately here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47156541/why-does-scalac-need-to-box-an-int-in-a-method-expecting-an-any

Comment: Doesn't `def print(): Unit = println(underlying.toString)` work to stop the wrapping of `underlying`? IOW, doesn't the use of `toString` enables the compiler to see the "intention" and make the static call as it does in other similar places?