# Why does scalac need to box an `Int` in a method expecting an `Any`

Tags: scala, boxing, scalac

Consider the following class:

```
package test
class Test {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val i: Int = 0
    println(i)
  }
}
```

The bytecode of `main` is:

```
public main([Ljava/lang/String;)V
   // parameter final  args
  L0
   LINENUMBER 4 L0
   ICONST_0
  L1
   ISTORE 2
  L2
   LINENUMBER 5 L2
   GETSTATIC scala/Predef$.MODULE$ : Lscala/Predef$;
   ILOAD 2
   INVOKESTATIC scala/runtime/BoxesRunTime.boxToInteger (I)Ljava/lang/Integer;
   INVOKEVIRTUAL scala/Predef$.println (Ljava/lang/Object;)V
  L3
   RETURN
  L4
   LOCALVARIABLE i I L1 L3 2
   LOCALVARIABLE this Ltest/Test; L0 L4 0
   LOCALVARIABLE args [Ljava/lang/String; L0 L4 1
   MAXSTACK = 2
   MAXLOCALS = 3
```

As can be seen, when we call `println`, the `Int` gets boxed into a `java.lang.Integer`. But the signature of `println` is:

```
def println(x: Any): Unit
```

As `Int <: AnyVal <: Any`, why does the `Int` need to get boxed in the call?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Any` can be syntactically used in Scala since the compiler auto boxes any Java primitive type (which is what `Int` is equivalent to) as needed. From the emitted byte code, you see that `INVOKEVIRTUAL` is called on a method with the following signature:

```
scala/Predef$.println (Ljava/lang/Object;)V
```

Since there is no notion of `Any` in Java, scalac emits method signature of `Object`, which in Scala is equivalent to `AnyRef`. Since `Int` extends `AnyVal`, we need to allocate the equivalent Java wrapper, which is `Integer`.

Comment: The follow-up question is _why on earth didn't they overload println, like Java has done?_

Comment: @oxbow_lakes Java does have primitive input types for `println`, and they all end up producing a `String` using `PrimitiveType.toString`, i.e. `Integer.toString`, which avoids allocation of an `Integer`. I'm assuming the implementer assumed that if you want to `println` in production, allocating an `Integer` or any other wrapper would be the least of your problems.

Comment: Except idiots like me might not think about this very much and blithely copy that style, unaware of the performance implications

Comment: As I asked on the other thread, doesn't `def print(): Unit = println(underlying.toString)` work to stop the wrapping of `underlying`? IOW, doesn't the use of `toString` enables the compiler to see the "intention" and make the static call as it does in other similar places?